# Getting elements from an array which adds up to a value greater than given value JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I recently just started to learn JavaScript to improve on my skills and a challenge came up which has thrown me off course.

I have a set of values of which I need to find elements in an array which would add up to give a number greater than the individual set of values. For instance

An array of [50, 100, 400, 800]

if I have a value say 50 it should return 50 as 50 is on the list. That is fine, but when If I have a value of say 421 it should return [400, 50] or if I have a value of 1751 it should return [800, 800, 100, 50, 50] as values that would add up to give the minimum value close to the given value.

I have tried the following:

1. I sorted the array values
2. Checked to see if the array includes a given value, if so return that value in a new array
3. If a value is less than min value and greater than the next value, return the next value
   I tried looking into reduce method but I cant get my head around it and would like some expertise please.

The following is my code

```js
const ItemSize = [50, 100, 400, 800]

function getItemSize(itemSize, n) {
  const sortedItemSizes = ItemSize.sort(function compare(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  let item = [];
  if (sortedItemSizes.includes(n)) {
    item.push(n);
  } else if (n > Math.min.apply(Math, sortedItemSizes) && n < sortedItemSizes[1]) {
    item.push(sortedItemSizes[1]);
  }

  return item;
}

console.log(
  getItemSize(ItemSize, 50)
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Sort the array in descending values
- Element by elment, check if it can be added to the solution, multiple times.
- Return the resulting array

```js
const arr = [50, 100, 800, 400];

function findSet(arr, sum) {
  const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => a < b ? 1 : -1);
  const res = [];
  sorted.forEach(n => {
    while(n <= sum) {
      sum -= n;
      res.push(n);
    }
  });
  return res;
}

console.log(findSet(arr, 51));
console.log(findSet(arr, 100));
console.log(findSet(arr, 150));
console.log(findSet(arr, 1751));
```

Comment: mmm  Op said..  `1751 it should return [800, 800, 100, 50, 50]`  you seem to be missing a 50, although I would have expected `[800, 800, 100, 100]` anyway.